# QTableView Sorting dates and values

Tags: python, sorting, pyside, qtableview

I have a table with some regular text, some numbers and dates, the text sorts fine, but the numbers and the dates aren't, this is because the value given is a string, not an int or a QDate object, what do I have to implement to get the actual int and the actual QDate item to sort it properly?

Is it in the ItemModel or in the TableView? Do I have to subclass it?

Comment: You can probably use a [QSortFilterProxyModel](http://srinikom.github.io/pyside-docs/PySide/QtGui/QSortFilterProxyModel.html#qsortfilterproxymodel) for this. Or you could try to change the types to int and QDate and it might sort properly by itself.

Comment: I see, in the link you provided says I can either 'implement PySide.QtGui.QSortFilterProxyModel.sort() in your model, or use a PySide.QtGui.QSortFilterProxyModel to wrap your model' How can I do the first one?

Comment: I don't think that will work. For the custom sorting you would have to implement that `lessThan` function for the proxy. I don't see that mentioned in the docs as a virtual method for the models.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to M4rtini I could implement the right function. For anyone strugling with it. Here's the code.

```
self.tableView = QtGui.TableView(self)
self.table_model = QtGui.QStandardItemModel(0, 0)
self.proxyModel = CustomSortingModel(self)

self.proxyModel.setSourceModel(self.table_model)
self.tableView.setModel(self.proxyModel)

class CustomSortingModel(QtGui.QSortFilterProxyModel):
    def lessThan(self,left,right):

        col = left.column()

        dataleft = left.data()
        dataright = right.data()

        if col == 2:
            dataleft = float(dataleft)
            dataright = float(dataright)
        elif col == 3:
            dataleft = QtCore.QDate.fromString(dataleft, "d/M/yy").addYears(100)
            dataright = QtCore.QDate.fromString(dataright, "d/M/yy").addYears(100)

        return dataleft < dataright
```